# TypeError: this.cliEngineCtor is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm running a react app using a yarn package manager.  I'm getting the aforementioned ESLint error.  I have tried the following to fix it:

1. Deleted package-lock.json and node modules and installed yarn and ran yarn init
2. Modified the eslint-plugin.js file to include the following at the top of the file:

> I used both of these at different times to no avail:

```
   this.CliEngineCtor = require(this.basicPath).CLIEngine;
   this.CliEngineCtor = require(this.basicPath).CLIEngineCtor;
```

Pertinent package.json entry:

```
{
  "name": "react-millionaire-quiz",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.7.0"
  },
```

I tried changing the eslint to lower versions, but that just created other problems breaking other dependencies and creating other errors.

How can this be fixed, or do I have to disable ESLint?

Comment: Your `TypeError` has nothing to do with ESLint. `TypeError`s are generated at runtime.

Comment: The TypeError occurs in eslint-plugin.js and if I disable it in Webstorm, the code runs with no problems.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on Intellij 2021.2 and ESlint 8.7.0 and using Yarn. TypeError: this.cliEngineCtor is not a constructor

Comment: I just installed 2021.3.1 and the problem went away.

Comment: @Sajad Asadi...that did it for me as well.

Comment: this error occurs only becuase your IDE doenst work with latest ESlint version. use lower ESlint or update IDE.